# How can I stop losing mapped drive connections to SimpleShare NAS device from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, nas

I have 4 mapped drives to a "SimpleShare" network storage device. 2 have no passwords and 2 have passwords. On Windows 7 Pro PCs, Randomly, 1 of the password protected drives loses connection. The dropped drive changes on different PCs.

Answer (score 3):

Windows has a idle timeout for mapped drive connections; by default it's 15 minutes.  This may be what you're running into.

The non-password protected drives reconnect as soon as you try to use them again (without asking for a password) so you probably don't notice they're doing it as well.

You can see how long your idle timeout is set to by opening a command prompt and typing:

```
net config server
```

You can set the timeout limit (in minutes) as such:

```
net config server /autodisconnect:<#ofminutes>
```

You can turn off the idle timeout completely by entering:

```
net config server /autodisconnect:-1
```

See this [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297684) for more info.

Hope that helps...